# how to have same rewrite rules for 2 different post type?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

i.e. by default, rewrite rules for page seems to be like:

```
'(.?.+?)/embed/?$' => string 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&embed=true' 
....
```

However, I want to set the rewrite rule, that works for `post` like `page` (i.e. `example.com/parent/child` hierarchy... plz, dont ask me why... i am working for [my plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-hierarchy-parent-to-post/))

as every attempt that makes those urls to work, breaks the `page` rules (and pages show 404).

which `add_rewrite_rule` i have to add? This method break pages (404):

```
$GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['post']->rewrite = array('with_front'=>false, 'slug'=>'/');
$GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['post']->query_var = 'post'; 
$GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['post']->add_rewrite_rules();
```

another method (this also breaks pages):

```
add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]*)/(.*)' , 'index.php?name=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

Comment: You can't do that with just a rewrite rule, given the path `some-parent/some-child/`, it's impossible to know if `some-child` is a page or a post without going to the database and looking.

Comment: @Milo but how WP works without problems, if you register custom post type rules? i.e. if you have CPT with  `slug1/slug2/`, then it doesnt make pages to break, and why posts break it?

btw, thanks so much for your answers.

Comment: and even a db method/functions, what i should use to check, i think `get_page_by_path` seems only way so?

Comment: CPTs have a static slug in the URL by default, like `/cpt/cpt-parent-slug/cpt-child-slug/`. There has to be something unique in the URL that doesn't change if you are only using rewrite rules to make it work.